# Move the content, not text, of a table's cell to the right

Tags: html-table

I have a series of nested tables, below I created a jsfiddle structure.
I was using the arab notation, ( `direction: rtl` ) which is obviously wrong. I can not find the right css that moves the content to the right.

I wish to recreate the same structure.
Without using `direction: rtl;` because this makes the text reversed too. Borders are only to highlight it better.

Thanks to anyone who can help me

https://jsfiddle.net/wo77wgL5/

```html
<table width = "800px" border=3 class="centralTable">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th>header 1</th>
<th>header 2</th>
<th>header 3</th>
<th>header 4</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Text 1</td>
<td>Text 2</td>
<td>Text 3</td>
<td>Text 4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=6 style= "direction:rtl;">
<table width = "500px" border=1 class="toTheRight">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th>header 11</th>
<th>header 22</th>
<th>header 33</th>
<th>header 44</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Text 11</td>
<td>Text 22</td>
<td>Text 33</td>
<td>Text 44</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<td align="right">`

https://jsfiddle.net/msp5m4k9

Comment: Yeah I thought that, forgot to mention, I am looking for a full CSS solution. Problem is when I use align="right" in the real table, it does not move to the right. It is exactly the same nested table. Just with fixed width on the cells.

Comment: Okay, found, there was a text-align=left in the css. removed, and align=right worked. Not css, but I got that going for me. thanks!